# Find Consecutive Date in SQL using 2 date columns

Tags: date, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I am trying to group by all consecutive patient admission to the table. If the patient re-admitted to the hospital next day( or within 24 hours), then I need to keep only one admission stay per patient. I appreciate your help.

0

| Patient_bed_id | Patientname | Hospital_In_date | Hospital_out_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Lukas | 1/1/2022 | 1/31/2022 |
| 111 | Lukas | 2/1/2022 | 2/28/2022 |
| 111 | Lukas | 3/1/2022 | 3/31/2022 |
| 111 | Lukas | 5/25/2022 | 6/2/2022 |
| 111 | Lukas | 8/1/2022 | 8/20/2022 |
| 111 | Lukas | 8/21/2022 | 9/10/2022 |
| 222 | Jason | 5/1/2022 | 5/3/2022 |
| 222 | Jason | 6/15/2022 | 7/11/2022 |
| 222 | Jason | 7/12/2022 | 7/26/2022 |
| 222 | Jason | 9/13/2022 | 9/15/2022 |
| 222 | Jason | 9/16/2022 | 9/27/2022 |

Final table

| Patient_bed_id | Patientname | Hospital_In_date | Hospital_out_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Lukas | 1/1/2022 | 3/31/2022 |
| 111 | Lukas | 5/25/2022 | 6/2/2022 |
| 111 | Lukas | 8/1/2022 | 9/10/2022 |
| 222 | Jason | 5/1/2022 | 5/3/2022 |
| 222 | Jason | 6/15/2022 | 7/26/2022 |
| 222 | Jason | 9/13/2022 | 9/27/2022 |

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please go to dbfiddle.uk and construct a fiddle there with your own server. By presenting your data as you have, you are basically asking us to type (a lot) of stuff into our systems - an error prone step. A fiddle can be a single source of truth for the question and eliminates duplication of effort on behalf of those trying to answer your question - help us to help you!

Answer (score 2):

```sql
WITH
cte1 AS (
    SELECT *,
           COALESCE(Hospital_In_date <> LAG(Hospital_out_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Patient_bed_id, Patientname ORDER BY Hospital_In_date) + INTERVAL 1 DAY, 0) not_consecutive
    FROM test
), 
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, 
           SUM(not_consecutive) OVER (PARTITION BY Patient_bed_id, Patientname ORDER BY Hospital_In_date) group_no
    FROM cte1
)
SELECT Patient_bed_id,
       Patientname,
       MIN(Hospital_In_date) Hospital_In_date,
       MAX(Hospital_out_Date) Hospital_out_Date
FROM cte2
GROUP BY Patient_bed_id, 
         Patientname, 
         group_no;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9ab6b3536780929f253438d45c76ace7), step-by-step.